# Firebase Dynamic Link: won't go to Apple App Store when app not installed

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Links that I create using REST work when the app is installed (they transfer the payload to my iOS app), but when the app isn't installed, the link goes to my website instead of the App Store.
The same (?) link created in the Console works fine. Can someone spot a problem in this call? THANK YOU

```
#!/bin/bash

api_key=MyAweSomeKey
domain=https://some.page.link
deep_link="https://someplace.com?my_payload=1"
android_app="com.someplace.human"
ios_app="com.someplace.banana"
appl_store_id="2024561111"

curl \
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --request 'POST' \
        --data @- \
        https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=$api_key <<EOP
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "domainUriPrefix": "$domain",
    "link": "$deep_link",
    "androidInfo": {
      "androidPackageName": "$android_app"
    },
    "iosInfo": {
      "iosBundleId": "$ios_app",
      "iosAppStoreId": "$apple_store_id"
    },
    "navigationInfo": {
      "enableForcedRedirect": true
    }
  },
  "suffix": {
    "option": "SHORT"
  }
}
EOP
```

Once iOS app is installed, this link works perfectly.
If app is not installed, it goes to the website instead of the store.

Comment: Is the App Store ID a real one for a live app that is in the App Store?

Comment: Jen - the one I posted above is a fake but the one I use for real is a good ID. Agree with you that this is where the problem must be since this variable is supposed to drive the session to the store, per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener), but unfortunately doesn't do so in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove navigationInfo[enableForcedRedirect]

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include [example] and an explanation of how this works and why it is of solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Comment: Thank you Timur. I tried but it doesn't help. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener), all that this variable does is handle situations where the link is received by an app that cannot ingest the payload, which isn't my case: _"if you expect a Dynamic Link to be opened only in apps that can open Dynamic Links reliably without this page, you can disable it with this parameter."_